# Find the average

Tags: statistics

So the question is simple if I have something like the salary of 10 workers is about $120 - 140$ and the salary of 8 workers is about $160-180$ and I have to find the average, how should I do that? Should I use as the average in the salary, for example, the average of $120 - 140$ is $130$ so 10 workers a getting $130$ and voters 8 workers are getting $170$ and then calculate?

Comment: Did you mean that the second range was $160-180$?  In any case, given how vague the data is, the method you describe is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @saulspatz yes 180, already corrected

Comment: @lulu there are more of these examples in my case, I gave only few of them trying to understand the concept of how should I do it

Comment: Well, the principle is fine.  The average of a group made up by subgroups is the weighted average of the sub group averages.  But, of course you didn't say that the average of the $10$, say, is $130$. Perhaps it is $120$ or $140$, we have no way of knowing.

Comment: You can assume everybody makes the low wage and take the average, and also that everybody makes the high wage and take the average.  These give you bounds on the maximum difference between the true average and your estimate.  But I don't think there's a better way of arriving at an estimate than what you propose.

Comment: @lulu and what if we have in the condition of the problem something like above 40 and to 15, should I take the minimum of these numbers like 41 and 14?

Comment: I don't understand the condition.

Comment: @lulu
$$ till 15 minutes we have 260 workers $$
$$ 15-20 minutes we have 350 workers$$
$$ 20-40 minutes we have 640 workers$$
$$ Above 40 minutes we have 250 workers$$

Comment: @lulu sorry I don`t actually know why didn`t my words go separate

Comment: If you have text in between dollar signs then spaces don't render.  You can always use the \text {...} operator to insert text.  In any case, it looks like you just have more subgroups, so use the method you already proposed.

Comment: @lulu thx, then I will do it as I proposed, good luck